# Is it possible to convert a &[T] or Vec<T> to Arc<Mutex<[T]>>?

Tags: rust, mutex, automatic-ref-counting

Consider the following

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};

fn arc_mutex_from_slice<T>(v: &[T]) -> Arc<Mutex<[T]>> {
    todo!();
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3];
    println!("{:#?}", arc_mutex_from_slice(&v[..]));
}
```

Is it possible to implement `arc_mutex_from_slice`? It is possible to implement this conversion for `Arc<Mutex<Box<[T]>>>` or `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>`, but both of those add another unnecessary allocation/indirection.

The type `Arc<Mutex<[T]>>` is valid and can be initialized when the slice's size is known.

```rust
let x = Arc::new(Mutex::new([1,2,3]));
```

But I can't find any way of achieving this when the slice's size is unknown. Naively trying to implement `arc_mutex_from_slice` as follows does not compile.

```rust
fn arc_mutex_from_slice<T>(v: &[T]) -> Arc<Mutex<[T]>> {
    return Arc::new(Mutex::new(*v));
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[T]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:21
  |
4 |     return Arc::new(Mutex::new(*v));
  |            -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |            |
  |            required by a bound introduced by this call
  |
  = help: within `Mutex<[T]>`, the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[T]`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `Mutex<[T]>`
note: required by a bound in `Arc::<T>::new`
```

Could any `unsafe` magic help with this?

Comment: A slice references some pre-existing data; a mutex owns its data. You cannot pretend you own something which is owned by someone else. You could eventually transfer ownership into the mutex but you would have to pass a value (`Vec`) not a reference (slice). You could also clone the original data in order to own this clone (not the original), but it is generally not what you want.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to construct a `Mutex` of an unsized type (safely or unsafely), except constructing a `Mutex` of a sized type and [unsizing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) it, because the internal layout of the `Mutex` is unspecified. So to construct a `Mutex<[T]>`, you **must** unsize a `Mutex<[T; N]>` because `[T; N]` are the only types that unsize to `[T]`, and you can't construct a `Mutex<[T]>` from a `Vec<T>` at all.

Comment: @prog-fh My intent was for the data to cloned from the input `&[T]` or `Vec<T>`. I suspect that what you are suggesting with consuming a `Vec<T>` and reusing its buffer is impossible in this case. Because `Mutex<[T]>` is necessarily larger than just `[T]`   and could exceed the size of `Vec<T>`'s internal buffer. Despite this, I still can't find a way to do this conversion even with cloning.

Comment: @Stargateur can you explain why it would be useless? I cannot see another way of sharing a buffer of mutable data with another thread without either having locks on every single element or having double indirection.

Comment: he was commenting about a *slice* (a reference), not an owned array. (difficult to guaranty anything about concurrent accesses)

Comment: @luctowers Why not simply `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>`? :)

Comment: @isaactfa I was interested in whether the double pointer indirection of having both `Arc` and `Vec` could be avoided. It doesn't seem like the double indirection is  strictly necessary, just hard to represent in rust without it.

Comment: I advice you to search for a specific type that is both arc and array on lib.rs, I didn't find that suit you perfectly https://lib.rs/crates/dyn_struct is mostly what you could do but you would need to adapt the code to have atomic counter. Anyway what you want is very very hard Rust and I can't stress enough that unless you have very good reason you should just live with double indirection.

Comment: @Stargateur that's fair enough, thank you. Double indirection isn't the end of the world, just wanted to check in-case there was an easy way around it I was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of writing, for safe Rust, you can do it, but only if the size of the array when allocation happens is known at compile time:

```
let v: Arc<Mutex<[u8]>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0;16]));
```

This essentially casts an `Arc<Mutex<[u8;16]>>` to an `Arc<Mutex<[u8]>>`.

However there is no way currently to do this safely with an array whose size is only known at runtime. The tricky part is that you would need to create the unsized `Mutex<[u8]>` and move it to the constructor of `Arc`, but moving values currently requires that the compiler knows their sizes.

[RFC 1909](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1909-unsized-rvalues.md) may help the situation, but has been open since 2017 with no end in sight.

---

As for `unsafe`... You could possibly allocate a section of memory that can hold both a `Mutex<()>` as well as the array, and access it manually via byte offsets. You have to be careful though - you may need padding in between the mutex and the array to satisfy the array element's alignment, and be sure you're not violating any aliasing or providence rules.

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled on that rfc in my search, quite unfortunate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your precise intention is.
I guess you want a thread-shareable array.

As stated in a comment, the array must be sized.
If this size is not imposed at compile-time, then you need to memorise a variable length (heap-allocated) array together with its size.
`Box<[T]>` is convenient for that.

Please find below three examples.
The first uses reference+clone, the second moves the original data.
In case the size is known at compile time, a third example avoids the extra indirection you seem to care about.

Note that, if we want only one indirection, then this one must be used by the various contexts (threads) in order to refer to the same mutex.
This implies that the block of memory containing this mutex must directly contain all the data.
If this size is not known at compile-time, this sounds like the *variable-size-struct ugly hack* we find sometimes in C (quite error-prone, not really in the spirit of Rust).

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn arc_mutex_from_slice_clone<T: Clone>(v: &[T]) -> Arc<Mutex<Box<[T]>>> {
    let owned = v.to_owned();
    let boxed = owned.into_boxed_slice();
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(boxed))
}

fn arc_mutex_from_vec<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> Arc<Mutex<Box<[T]>>> {
    let boxed = v.into_boxed_slice();
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(boxed))
}

fn arc_mutex_sized_from_vec<T: std::fmt::Debug, const N: usize>(
    v: Vec<T>
) -> Arc<Mutex<[T; N]>> {
    let array = v.try_into().unwrap();
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(array))
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let m1 = arc_mutex_from_slice_clone(v1.as_slice());
    println!("m1: {:?}", m1);
    // v1 is still usable since m1 contains a clone
    println!("v: {:?}", v1);
    let m2 = arc_mutex_from_vec(v1);
    println!("m2: {:?}", m2);
    // v1 is not usable anymore since is it moved int m2
    // println!("v: {:?}", v1);
    //
    let v2 = vec![6, 7, 8, 9];
    let m3 = arc_mutex_sized_from_vec::<_, 4>(v2);
    println!("m3: {:?}", m3);
}
/*
m1: Mutex { data: [1, 2, 3], poisoned: false, .. }
v: [1, 2, 3]
m2: Mutex { data: [1, 2, 3], poisoned: false, .. }
m3: Mutex { data: [6, 7, 8, 9], poisoned: false, .. }
*/
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a thread-shareable array of mutable data with a lock that is shared among all elements. I wanted to see whether there was a way to avoid the double indirection of having both `Arc` and `Box`. But, it seems like it may not be possible.

Comment: @luctowers I added a third example without the extra indirection. This implies that the size is known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you :) I don't know the size of my vec at compile-time, so won't work for me. But, I hadn't seen those const generics used like that before so that may come in handy for something else!